# Couldn't set gain on joystick force feedback: Bad file descriptor

Tags: linux, ros, descriptor, joystick

I have a **xbox 360** joystick. 
I'm currently have trouble with connecting my joystick to PC. 
 
I've searched the information about this. 
My device is connected on **/dev/input/js0**

1. I did below two tests successfully!

```sh
$ jstest /dev/input/js0
$ jstest-gtk
```

2. I did also,

```sh
$ sudo chmod a+rw /dev/input/js0
```

Whenever I type that line

```sh
$ rosrun joy joy_node dev:=/dev/input/js0
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A84OP.png)

Anyone has an experience solving the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stumbled upon this. Just for completion: the question seems to be answered in an issue of the corresponding ros package [here](https://github.com/ros-drivers/joystick_drivers/issues/134).